# How can we run protractor specs in firefox?

Tags: node.js, protractor

Can we run protractor on Firefox for automation? Is it possible to specify the version of Firefox, selenium, nodejs. I tried this code :

```
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'firefox' // or 'safari'
},
```

Comment: yes, you can run protractor on firefox. And why do you need  the version of selenium and nodeJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can run the protractor on specific version of browser. You need to mention the version in capabilities section. You can use below code:

**Code Snippet**:

```
      capabilities: {
          'browserName':'firefox',
          'version': 'ANY'
    },
```